# How do i only update 1 column in gridview?

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview with multiple columns however I only want to update one of these columns in the database. I have set all other columns to read only so that the only editable field is the one I want to edit however when I update this field all others get deleted but I want them to remain the same. How do I accomplish this?
Thanks

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: @d99: Instead of `BoundField` Use `TemplateField` , refer http://satindersinght.blogspot.in/2012/08/how-to-addupdate-record-using-gridview.html complete article

Answer (score 0):

Make the gridview fields TemplateFields, you can then access the EditItemTemplate of the fields. In the editItemTemplate, instead of Textbox( by default) you replace the textbox with a Label for the fields for which you don't want the edit facility.

similar question here http://forums.asp.net/t/1099084.aspx/1

Answer (score 0):

When You are updating your data base values you can also update all other values which read only. and one editable column value change each time .